# Is it possible to add an item the Post Publish panel?

Tags: wp-admin

In the Admin area when you edit a post, I'd like to add a custom item to the Publish panel in the top right corner.

Is it possible to access this through the Wordpress API? If so, what functions do I need to look at? Any examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can hook into `'post_submitbox_misc_actions'` or `'post_submitbox_start'`:

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'wpse_45720_submitdiv_extra' );
add_action( 'post_submitbox_start', 'wpse_45720_submitdiv_extra' );

function wpse_45720_submitdiv_extra()
{
    print '<pre>' . current_filter() . '</pre>';
}
```